# Objects in small column or margin (layout)

Tags: margins

I would like to layout a report in "columns" - however, not traditional columns equally wide as newspapers etc. (easily done with the cuted package and \onecolumn and \twocolumn). The concept should be a "large" column to the right for most of the content, including all body text, and a "narrow/small" column to the left for small figures, captions etc. The catch is that sometimes I also need objects to span the full width.

To sum up, I need the small column to be able to contain the following elements (also visualized in the attached figure):

- Small figures, including their caption
- Capions for the normal figures in the large column
- Objects in full width (large + small column)
- Section and subsection numbering

Can anybody help with a solution? I don't know whether it should be solved with the use of columns, (par)boxes, creative use of margins or something else.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Jesper

[image: Layout wish]

Comment: @epR8GaYuh  How do you know my password? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I guess that you are looking for something similar to the so-called **Tufte style** (after [Edward Tufte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte)).
- CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex
- tex.stackexchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tufte

[image]

*The image is taken from the sample document from `tufte-latex` (CTAN link, see above).*

Comment: Wauw, this looks very promising! Nice "coincidence" that the package hits all 3 of my wishes with regard to figures.

I will try to make time to look closer into the tufte-latex package. Thank you very much so far Dr. Manuel Kuehner!

Comment: @JesperNørgaard If the answer was helpful, then accept it (green check mark on the left side) and/or upvote it. This is how a question is closed.

Comment: Yes, I know from other communities :) I thought I would buy a few days to look closer into the package, but I will accept the answer already - with high expectations to the package :)